# How to add values to a form before submitting it with Django?

Tags: django, django-forms

I need help with what might be a simple problem. I am writing a form to add a section to some unit. The unit will have X sections tied to it, sorted with indexes (indices?).

The problem arises when I try to pass the unit_id to the section. As the user will need to pass through the unit screen to add a section, I want it to be automatically assigned, it'll be in the URL too.

I am encountering problems adding it to the modelform, after submitting the value entered by the user.

```
def section_modify(request, unit_id, section_id=None):
    unit = get_object_or_404(Models.Unit, id=int(unit_id))
    if section_id is not None:
        section = get_object_or_404(Models.Section, id=int(section_id))
    else:
        section = None
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = F.SectionForm(request.POST, instance=section)
        if form.is_valid():
            # I tried this part, but it didn't work:
            #  form.save(commit=False)
            #  form.unit_id = unit_id
            form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('') 
    else: 
        form = F.SectionForm(instance=section) 
    return render(request, 'sectionEdit.html', {'form': form})
```

I am looking for the least hacky way to do this, django way.

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3):

Try to add unit_id like this:

```
if form.is_valid():
     # section will get unsaved model instance 
     # so you can assign property value and then save
     section = form.save(commit=False)
     section.unit_id = unit_id
     section.save()
```

*** UPDATED ***

```
def section_modify(request, unit_id, section_id=None):
    unit = get_object_or_404(Models.Unit, id=int(unit_id))
    if section_id is not None:
        section = get_object_or_404(Models.Section, id=int(section_id))
        if section:
            section.unit_id=unit.pk
            section.save()
    else:
        section = None
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = F.SectionForm(request.POST, instance=section)
        if form.is_valid():
            if section:
                form.save()
            else:
               section = form.save(commit=False)
               section.unit_id=unit.pk
               section.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('') 
    else: 
        form = F.SectionForm(instance=section) 
    return render(request, 'sectionEdit.html', {'form': form})
```

So if we have section instance append unit_id to it else append unit'id after form submit.